# Does a zero integral over a set of a positive almost everywhere function imply that that set has measure 0?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space.  Let $f$ be measurable on $X$, $f > 0$ almost everywhere.  Let $E \in \mathcal{M}$.  If
\begin{align*}
\int_E f \, d\mu = 0,
\end{align*}
is it true that $\mu(E) = 0$?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Consider the chain of sets $\{ x \in X : f(x) \ge 1/n \}$. All these have measure zero, and their union has measure zero complement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Wlog $f>0$ everywhere because that doesn't change the integral $\int_Ef\,d\mu$. Now,
$$\int_Ef\,d\mu=\int_X\chi_E f\,d\mu=0,$$
(where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E$) and since $\chi_E f$ is non-negative this implies that
$$\mu(\{x\in X:\chi_E(x)f(x)\neq 0\})=0.$$
But
$$\{x\in X:\chi_E(x)f(x)\neq 0\}=E.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Consider that $\int_Ef \, d\mu = \int_Xf1_E \, d\mu$. This implies that $f1_E$ is zero almost everywhere, and since $f$ is nonzero almost everywhere, $1_E$ must be zero almost everywhere, hence $E$ is a zero set.